# Why is Angular Material elements not visible in the page?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have implemented the following Angular Material elements but they are not visible on the page. there are no errors, the transpiled code is showing in the developer console but the elements are not visible on the page.

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Sizes</mat-label>
    <mat-select [(value)]="item.size" class="text-center" (selectionChange)="showSize($event.value)">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let size of staticData.sizes" [value]="size">
            {{size}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Can you please add the surrounding code too? It is something outside those 10 lines that hides the mat-select. Especially if you have no errors and you are certain that staticData.sizes have values.

Comment: The material element is enclosed in the following div element: <div class="col-9 text-center d-md-flex justify-content-md-center align-items-md-center">

Comment: If you can provide stackblitz that will help solve a problem